# golang nil pointer assignment with ignored output - (*)(nil)

Tags: pointers, go

while going through [this](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2014/fuse-zipfs/) tutorial on writing FUSE filesystems in go, I came across this cryptic assignment:

```
var _ fs.Node = (*Dir)(nil)
```

Can someone explain the mechanics of this syntax, and how does it fit in the context in which it is declared? As I understand the outcome of the assignment is actually ignored (and what does the right hand expression even result in? a nil Dir pointer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes the compiler check if type `*Dir` fulfills `fs.Node` interface.

Take a `nil` pointer, make it a `*Dir` pointer and assign it to an unnamed variable of interface type `fs.Node`. Since we never use this variable, we have to make it unnamed.